# How to remove Cortana from search button in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: settings, 8.1, cortana

How to remove Cortana from the search button in Windows Phone 8.1? I want my original Bing screen back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable Cortana with the following steps...

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Swipe across to **Applications** and tap on **Cortana** so see its settings
3. Toggle the switch to **Off**, you'll be prompted to restart your phone
4. After the restart, tapping the Search button will bring up the old Bing Search interface.

*Note:* you can always re-activate Cortana by running the Cortana app again.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work in Windows 10? There is no longer an 'Applications' item in 'Settings'.

Comment: @posfan12 you'll have to ask a new question about that :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to switch faster between Cortana and Bing Search, just add "Location Services" to the Action Center (Settings > Notifications + actions). Then, you can toggle location services to enable or disable Cortana.

When you want to use Cortana, enable location services from the Action Center. 
And when you want to use Bing Search, turn off location services.